# True Colour Composite image is Red. I have used sentinel2 images

Tags: qgis, composite

I am trying to do Land Use Land Cover Analysis on QGIS using sentinel-2, however when I try to do composite band with band 4,3,2, the image is predominantly red and nowhere close the what it should be. The area is full of vegetaion and snow. [image]

Comment: The max values you see for the bands are probably from outlying pixels. Try adjusting these values to see how it changes the look of the image. You can also expand the *Min / Max Value Settings* menu and try different methods of clipping the values. Cumulative Count Cut generally works quite well. You may need to increase the min and decrease the max to increase the effect.